# Accessing animated properties from script

Tags: python, animation

I have a camera with animated transforms (loc, rot) and the focal length. I need to find out if the camera's lens is animated.
my_cam.animation_data has 1 action, the transforms. The action editor also only shows the transforms keyframes, however the dope sheet suggests, there are 2 actions on the camera
[image]

'CameraAction' and 'Camera'.
bpy.data.actions contains 'CameraAction' and 'CameraAction.001', the latter holds the f-curve for the focal length animation. But I can't be sure whether it's from this camera or another, or even orphan data.
So how can I find *all* animated channels of an object not just the transforms ones?

Comment: `CameraAction` is the only one that's related to object. `Camera` is not related to the object `bpy.data.objects["Camera"]` but to its object data `bpy.data.objects["Camera"].data` that's a different datablock.

Comment: dang, I tried this, but didn't look properly at the datapath of *that* action's fcurve. Thanks.